# what kinds of geometry is suitable for rendering tree branches

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, rendering

Recently I'm doing a project to rendering trees.
At my first thought, I chose the cylinder to represent one small branch. But I have got **seams** in the result:
[image]

Then I look into a famous tree modeling software "**SpeedTree**", it goes rather smoothly between 2 branches:

[image]
And  I saw its underlying wireframes, it's like below:

[image]

So I'm wondering **what kind of geometry has SpeedTree used for branch representation**? It seems not to use cylinder because two faces are not parallel. And is it hard to implement such geometry in Opengl?

---

**Update:**
I decided to use spline as the underlying skeleton of a branch just like SpeedTree, but which kinds of splines is best for this purpose?

Comment: This looks potentially relevant: http://docs.speedtree.com/doku.php?id=branchintersections

Comment: @StuartGolodetz It seems that this doc just gives a few comments on the underlying implementation, is there any link that can give detailed explanation? Because I'm kind of new to 3d graphics.

Comment: Not sure unfortunately - I just did a quick Google to see what I could dig up for you.

Answer (score 0):

It could work to use a [geometry shader](http://open.gl/geometry) to generate the mesh of the tree. You could conceivably "draw" each branch as a `GL_LINE_STRIP_ADJACENCY`, and then let the geometry shader generate the triangle strip that would be the quasi-cylinder for each branch segment.

The reason this approach would help with the seams is that you could adjust where the edges of the cylinder-ish object are based on the angle/location/radius of the prev/next branch segment. It would also allow the radius of the cylinder to vary from end-to-end: as the branch becomes thinner, the transition would happen smoothly, rather than having each segment step down in radius abruptly at the seams.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL just renders groups of triangles. It is up to you to specify how they connect. Most likely, SpeedTree is computing the locations of the vertices without the help of any rendering API like OpenGL.

From the wireframe you posted, it looks like SpeedTree is generating the centers and radius of the tree branches at various positions along their length. Each one of these data points seems to become a ring of n vertices, which it then connects to be preceding control point with a strip of triangles.

For efficiency reasons, SpeedTree probably packs all the vertices into a single VBO/IBO pair for rendering.